# How to change the value of a global variable inside a class in Python?

Tags: python, class, variables, global-variables

I want to assign a new value to a global variable, but its not working

```
email = " "
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        ---some code---
    def assign_email(self):
        email = "max@gmail.com"
class B()
    def __init__(self):
        print(email)            #this returns an empty string, not the updated value "max@gmail.com"
```

Comment: use global, i.e. replace `email = "max@gmail.com"` with `global email = "max@gmail.com"`. i think it should work. i would add a note: this is not a very good way of structuring your code and the use of global should be very limited since it is confusing to understand where the email param got his value from.

Comment: Consider making `email` a class/instance variable unless you really know what you're doing and you have to have that global variable.

Answer (score 1):

you should declare `email` is the global variable and not local.
you can do it with:
`global email`

```
email = " "
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
        # ---some code---
    def assign_email(self):
        global email # this makes email to be the global email
        email = "max@gmail.com"
class B():
    def __init__(self):
        print(email)            #this returns an empty string, not the updated value "max@gmail.com"
a = A()
a.assign_email()
b = B()
print(email) # global email
```

Comment: Yes this does work. But somehow the same is not working in my python-kivy code